# Is there short Pandas method chain for assigning grouped nth value?

Tags: python, pandas

I use nth value as columns without row aggregation.
Because I want to create a feature that can be tracked by using the window function and the aggregation function at any time.

R:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% arrange(Species, Sepal.Length) %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(cs = cumsum(Sepal.Length), cs4th = cumsum(Sepal.Length)[4]) %>%
  slice(c(1:4))

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species       cs cs4th
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1          4.3         3            1.1         0.1 setosa       4.3  17.5
 2          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa       8.7  17.5
 3          4.4         3            1.3         0.2 setosa      13.1  17.5
 4          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa      17.5  17.5
 5          4.9         2.4          3.3         1   versicolor   4.9  20  
 6          5           2            3.5         1   versicolor   9.9  20  
 7          5           2.3          3.3         1   versicolor  14.9  20  
 8          5.1         2.5          3           1.1 versicolor  20    20  
 9          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7 virginica    4.9  22  
10          5.6         2.8          4.9         2   virginica   10.5  22  
11          5.7         2.5          5           2   virginica   16.2  22  
12          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica   22    22
```

Python: Too long and verbose!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

iris.sort_values(['species','sepal_length']).assign(
index_species=lambda x: x.groupby('species').cumcount(),
cs=lambda x: x.groupby('species').sepal_length.cumsum(),
tmp=lambda x: np.where(x.index_species==3, x.cs, 0),
cs4th=lambda x: x.groupby('species').tmp.transform(sum)
).iloc[list(range(0,4))+list(range(50,54))+list(range(100,104))]


     sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  ...    cs   tmp  cs4th
13            4.3          3.0           1.1  ...   4.3   0.0   17.5
8             4.4          2.9           1.4  ...   8.7   0.0   17.5
38            4.4          3.0           1.3  ...  13.1   0.0   17.5
42            4.4          3.2           1.3  ...  17.5  17.5   17.5
57            4.9          2.4           3.3  ...   4.9   0.0   20.0
60            5.0          2.0           3.5  ...   9.9   0.0   20.0
93            5.0          2.3           3.3  ...  14.9   0.0   20.0
98            5.1          2.5           3.0  ...  20.0  20.0   20.0
106           4.9          2.5           4.5  ...   4.9   0.0   22.0
121           5.6          2.8           4.9  ...  10.5   0.0   22.0
113           5.7          2.5           5.0  ...  16.2   0.0   22.0
101           5.8          2.7           5.1  ...  22.0  22.0   22.0
```

Python : My better solution(not smart. There is room for improvement about specifications of groupby )

```
iris.sort_values(['species','sepal_length']).assign(
    cs=lambda x: x.groupby('species').sepal_length.transform('cumsum'),
    cs4th=lambda x: x.merge(
        x.groupby('species', as_index=False).nth(3).loc[:,['species','cs']],on='species')
        .iloc[:,-1]
    )
```

This doesn't work in a good way

```
iris.groupby('species').transform('nth(3)')
```

Comment: sample input data and expected output would be helpful

Comment: I added Python data importing. My expected output is just as R's. I want to use pandas code more shorter without assigning verbose columns

Comment: I put more details. I want nth value at each group. So, that is why pandas code is too long and verbose. Is there short Pandas method chain for assigning grouped nth value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated solution, using Pandas, which is still longer than what you will get with dplyr:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

iris['cs'] = (iris
              .sort_values(['species','sepal_length'])
              .groupby('species')['sepal_length']
              .transform('cumsum'))

M = (iris
     .sort_values(['species','cs'])
     .groupby('species')['cs'])
```

groupby has a nth function that gets you a row per group : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html

```
iris = (iris
        .sort_values(['species','cs'])
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .merge(M.nth(3), how='left', on='species')
        .rename(columns={'cs_x':'cs',
                         'cs_y':'cs4th'})
        )

iris.head()
    sepal_length    sepal_width     petal_length    petal_width  species         cs     cs4th
0       4.3             3.0             1.1             0.1       setosa        4.3      17.5
1       4.4             2.9             1.4             0.2       setosa        8.7      17.5
2       4.4             3.0             1.3             0.2       setosa       13.1      17.5
3      4.4              3.2             1.3             0.2       setosa       17.5      17.5 
4      4.5              2.3             1.3             0.3       setosa       22.0      17.5
```

Update: 16/04/2021 ... Below is a better way to achieve the OP's goal:

```
(iris
.sort_values(['species', 'sepal_length'])
.assign(cs = lambda df: df.groupby('species')
                          .sepal_length
                          .transform('cumsum'), 
        cs4th = lambda df: df.groupby('species')
                             .cs
                             .transform('nth', 3)
        )
.groupby('species')
.head(4)
)

     sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width     species    cs  cs4th
13            4.3          3.0           1.1          0.1      setosa   4.3   17.5
8             4.4          2.9           1.4          0.2      setosa   8.7   17.5
38            4.4          3.0           1.3          0.2      setosa  13.1   17.5
42            4.4          3.2           1.3          0.2      setosa  17.5   17.5
57            4.9          2.4           3.3          1.0  versicolor   4.9   20.0
60            5.0          2.0           3.5          1.0  versicolor   9.9   20.0
93            5.0          2.3           3.3          1.0  versicolor  14.9   20.0
98            5.1          2.5           3.0          1.1  versicolor  20.0   20.0
106           4.9          2.5           4.5          1.7   virginica   4.9   22.0
121           5.6          2.8           4.9          2.0   virginica  10.5   22.0
113           5.7          2.5           5.0          2.0   virginica  16.2   22.0
101           5.8          2.7           5.1          1.9   virginica  22.0   22.0
```

Comment: I put more details. I want nth value at each group. So, that is why pandas code is too long and verbose. Is there short Pandas method chain for assigning grouped nth value?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know nth function. Nearly there! It is perfect if `iris.groupby('species').transform('nth(3)')` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do it in a non-verbose way as you did in R with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) in python:

```py
>>> from datar.datasets import iris
>>> from datar.all import f, arrange, mutate, cumsum, slice
>>> 
>>> (iris >> 
...  arrange(f.Species, f.Sepal_Length) >>
...  group_by(f.Species) >>
...  mutate(cs=cumsum(f.Sepal_Length), cs4th=cumsum(f.Sepal_Length)[3]) >>
...  slice(f[1:4]))
    Sepal_Length  Sepal_Width  Petal_Length  Petal_Width     Species    cs  cs4th
0            4.3          3.0           1.1          0.1      setosa   4.3   17.5
1            4.4          2.9           1.4          0.2      setosa   8.7   17.5
2            4.4          3.0           1.3          0.2      setosa  13.1   17.5
3            4.4          3.2           1.3          0.2      setosa  17.5   17.5
4            4.9          2.4           3.3          1.0  versicolor   4.9   20.0
5            5.0          2.0           3.5          1.0  versicolor   9.9   20.0
6            5.0          2.3           3.3          1.0  versicolor  14.9   20.0
7            5.1          2.5           3.0          1.1  versicolor  20.0   20.0
8            4.9          2.5           4.5          1.7   virginica   4.9   22.0
9            5.6          2.8           4.9          2.0   virginica  10.5   22.0
10           5.7          2.5           5.0          2.0   virginica  16.2   22.0
11           5.8          2.7           5.1          1.9   virginica  22.0   22.0
[Groups: ['Species'] (n=3)]
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.